# Excel merge/Concat two dynamic ranges into a single range

Tags: excel, merge, range, concatenation, rows

If I have the following dynamic lists, length determined by the last blank row.
range=A1:A5

```
   AAA
    BBB
    CCC
    <blank>
    <blank>
```

and, range=B1:B3

```
111
222
<blank>
```

How can I create a new list/range that has the two ranges joined together without the blanks.
range=C1:C8

```
    AAA
    BBB
    CCC
    111
    222
<blank>
<blank>
<blank>
```

Comment: Last blank row could be the end of the sheet. Is list 1 always pulled from A1:A5 and list 2 from B1:B3?

Comment: yes, assume so. But the number of blank cells in each of those ranges are dynamic. I simplified the example. Initially thought to use TEXTJOIN which you can ignore blanks, but now not sure how to covert it back to a range.

Comment: So, if there is something after the last blank row it will be ignored?

Comment: Yes, you can assume the first blank row is the end of the list. I can do it using a temporary column as a key, but looking for a single formula I can type into C1:C8, either as an array, or fill down.

Answer (score 0):

This was the convoluted way I managed to get it to work, most likely there is something much more succinct

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1,INDEX($B$1:$B$8,ROW(C1)-ROW($C$1)-COUNTA($A$1:$A$8)+1))
```